# OpenGL and wglUseFontBitmaps only draws equally spaced letters

Tags: winapi, opengl, fonts

the fonts I draw in OpenGL by using wglUseFontBitmaps take equal space (width) for every letter, so a "." needs as much space as an "M" for example. I have changed the pitch paramter in font creation to `VARIABLE_PITCH` but it doesnt change anything. Can it actually be done with wglUseFontBitmaps or is it its nature that every generated bitmap takes equal space?

Furthermor I am querying the width/height of the rastered bitmap text with GetTextExtentPoint32W(). The width returned is ok but the height is always too big. I am drawing a bright rectangle behind the black text to make it always readable within the 3d scene. Why is the queried height so big? Is the space reserved for higher characters something like this "É"?

My Setup:

```
HFONT   font;                                       // Windows Font ID
font = CreateFont(  -12,                            // Height Of Font
        0,                              // Width Of Font
        0,                              // Angle Of Escapement
        0,                              // Orientation Angle
        FW_EXTRALIGHT,                      // Font Weight
        FALSE,                          // Italic
        FALSE,                          // Underline
        FALSE,                          // Strikeout
        ANSI_CHARSET,                   // Character Set Identifier
        OUT_TT_PRECIS,                  // Output Precision
        CLIP_DEFAULT_PRECIS,            // Clipping Precision
        ANTIALIASED_QUALITY,            // Output Quality
        FF_DONTCARE | VARIABLE_PITCH,       // Family And Pitch
        (LPCWSTR)L"Arial");             // Font Name

    SelectObject(this->hDeviceContext, font);

     //init display lists for text drawing
    bool createFontLists = wglUseFontBitmaps(this->hDeviceContext, 0, 255, 1000);
```

Comment: This isn't an answer but rather a suggestion:  Don't use this.  If you want to draw fonts using OpenGL, use FreeType.  It's a much better library for this sort of thing.  There are a few open source libraries which wrap freetype and opengl together.  I believe FTGL is the most mature.  Best of luck.

Comment: Thx. I had a look on FTGL, but wanted to do without it, but I think now it might be a better solution to use such a library.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I solved the problem myself: It only looks like the font draws every letter with equal space or monospaced, but actually OpenGL drawed a space " " between every character. The problem was the usage of `std::wstring` for calling the displaylists generated with `wglUseFontBitmaps`.
Wrong drawing looked like this:

```
int length = wcslen(text.c_str());
glCallLists (sizeof(wchar_t) * length, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, text.c_str());
```

The first parameters (number of lists to be called) is wrong. It has to be `length` only. The second parameter, telling OpenGL how to interpret every character in the text.c_str as an offset number defining the next display list to call is wrong here. It has to be GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT which is 2Bytes from 0-65535. With GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE every '0' used for the second byte in the wstring for the 2-Byte character was interpreted as a space. So the correct call is:

```
glCallLists (length, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, text.c_str());
```

This works for my case, but is not a general way to use unicode charaters with wglUseFontBitmaps. It only safely covers the ASCII characters coming from a wstring here.